# Spark Structured Streaming: "earliest" as "startingOffsets" is not working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

My Spark Structured Streaming job works fine when I set "startingOffsets" to "latest". When I simply changed it to "earliest" & specified a new "check point directory", the job doesn't work. The states don't get timed out after 10 minutes.

While debugging I noticed that my 'state' logic is indeed getting executed but states just don't time out - as they do when I use "latest". Any reason why?

Is this a known issue?

**Note**: I've tried this under Spark 2.3 & 2.4

Answer (score 1):

After I set the 'maxOffsetsPerTrigger' to a value such as '200000', it started working.